# How to change flutter plugin package name

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

When I try to publish my plugin  with `pub publish --dry-run` I got the following error.

```
Package name "SampleSDK" should be lower-case. Maybe use "sample_sdk"?
```

How can I change the package name ? There is lots of info to change the app package name but I think it is different. I tried but messed up several times to change the package name.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your package name in `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: I get the error as

 `Error on line 1, column 7 of ../pubspec.yaml: "name" field doesn't match expected name "SampleSDK"`

Comment: Did you try running `flutter clean`?

Comment: I had the same issue but I realized it was actually coming from my example project where I forgot to update the name of the package in its own pubspec file

Answer (score 0):

Yup you should modify the name of your plugin to lowercase

i.e:

```
flutter create --template--package sample_anything_in_the_world
```

check this :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FA_fvRSoSE&list=PLhXZp00uXBk5TSY6YOdmpzp1yG3QbFvrN&index=42

Comment: Are you recommending to create a new plugin?